# Jenkins REST API /input request not working. Can't resume a paused job

Tags: jenkins

Version: jenkins latest

## Problem summary

I have some code that is calling the Jenkins REST API to resume a suspended job. The job was suspended by an input() statement.

My REST request to resume the job work sometimes but not always. Specifically, the request will succeed if the job was suspended recently (i.e. a minute or so), but if I wait a few minutes before making the request to resume the job, Jenkins returns a 404 not found error.

## Details

*Jenkins config*

- Security is disabled.
- CSRF tokens are disabled
- Both Jenkins and the REST client are on the same machine. This is a corporate network with a proxy.

*Jenkins extract*

```
stage('Approve') {
    when {
        expression { BRANCH_NAME ==~ BRANCH_QA }
    }
    steps {
        script {
            env.IS_APPROVED = input(
                id: env.JOB_ID,
                message: "Approve release?",
                ok: "y",
                parameters: [
                    string(name: 'IS_APPROVED', defaultValue: 'y', description: 'Deploy to master?')
                ]
            )
            if (env.IS_APPROVED != 'y') {
                currentBuild.result = "ABORTED"
                error "User cancelled"
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

**REST call to resume the suspended jenkins job**

*Request*

http://localhost:9000/job/sirgis-poc/job/qa-dev-35cdedcf-7f88-46e6-bc2e-c805441e5269/1/input/35cdedcf-7f88-46e6-bc2e-c805441e5269/submit?nonce=745493
json={"parameter":[{"name":"IS_APPROVED","value":"y"}]}&proceed=y

*Response*

If the REST request was made immediately after Jenkins paused the job, the response is:

```
StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: 

System.Net.Http.NoWriteNoSeekStreamContent, Headers:
{
  Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate, no-cache
  Date: Wed, 11 Apr 2018 02:02:50 GMT
  Server: Jetty(9.4.z-SNAPSHOT)
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  X-Hudson-Theme: default
  X-Hudson: 1.395
  X-Jenkins: 2.107.1
  X-Jenkins-Session: 20efd199
  X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
  Content-Length: 17885
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
  Expires: 0
}
```

If I wait a few minutes, then make the request, Jenkins returns the following.

```
StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: 

System.Net.Http.NoWriteNoSeekStreamContent, Headers:
{
  Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate, no-cache
  Date: Wed, 11 Apr 2018 05:19:41 GMT
  Server: Jetty(9.4.z-SNAPSHOT)
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  Content-Length: 429
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### TLDR

the input step ID must start with an upper case letter.

**Details**

There is a known Jenkins issue, where REST calls to resume a paused job can fail, if the input step ID does not begin with an uppercase letter.

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34509